# "Could not write metadata for '/STM32H750B-DK'."

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

This is the error msg in STM32CubeIDE

Could not write metadata for '/STM32H750B-DK'.
C:\WorkspacesCube.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\STM32H750B-DK.markers.snap (The system cannot find the path specified)

I tried to create a project and I can't find the "application" folder.

The operating system I use is windows. When I click on the app STM32CubeIDE, new file, I choose my board STM32H750-DK and than "finish" after I chose my board this error appears.

Comment: How does it happen? When? When you click what? "I tried to create a project and I can't find the "application" folder." - this gives no useful information. Please, describe your hardware setup, software setup and a full sequence of actions that led to a problem, preferably down to the last mouse click, as well as what you tried to resolve it. You didn't even say if it's Windows or Mac or some Linux.

Comment: The operating system I use is windows. When I click on the app STM32CubeIDE, new file, I choose my board STM32H750-DK and than "finish" after I chose my board this error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .metadata folder and it works.

Comment: could be write permissions for the folder were off. You deleted it, and the Cube created it again with proper permissions, or something of this sort. Glad you got it sorted out. Don't forget to accept your own answer so the question is closed